# How to call GL.IssuePlugInEvent in Unity3d and pass parameters to the plugin side in C

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es, android-unity-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin for Unity that passes information between the native side of android (but same may apply to any other dll or so library) and the unity side. The information I want to share is OpenGL related. On Unity docs it's specified that everything that has to run on the rendering thread must be called through The `GL.IssuePlugInEvent` function. This function though is quite strict on the parameters: it needs a to call a function with a specific signature:

> Callback must be a native function of "void UNITY_INTERFACE_API UnityRenderingEvent(int eventId)" signature

and has only the additional parameter eventId.

How can I then pass back on the unity side information from the so library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unity examples for creating a plugin and using IssuePluginEvent cover the case where you want/need to call directly a C function, and this function accepts only an eventId as parameter. If the reader comes from a C\C++ background and is not familiar with C#, it may be misleading. In fact, you can actually call a C# function with this simple trick, and inside that function call your C functions passing multiple parameters.
The steps are:

1. get a function pointer for a C# function (notice that the function will be static)
2. pass that function pointer to GL.IssuePluginEvent
3. inside your static C# function, based on the case of eventId, call the appropriate C function

```cs
    void Update()
    {
        GL.IssuePluginEvent(RenderThreadHandlePtr, GL_INIT_EVENT); // example
    }

    /// <summary> Renders the event delegate described by eventID. </summary>
    /// <param name="eventID"> Identifier for the event.</param>
    private delegate void RenderEventDelegate(int eventID);
    /// <summary> Handle of the render thread. </summary>
    private static RenderEventDelegate RenderThreadHandle = new RenderEventDelegate(RunOnRenderThread);
    /// <summary> The render thread handle pointer. </summary>
    public static IntPtr RenderThreadHandlePtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(RenderThreadHandle);

    public const int GL_INIT_EVENT = 0x0001;
    public const int GL_DRAW_EVENT = 0x0002;

    /// <summary> Executes the 'on render thread' operation. </summary>
    /// <param name="eventID"> Identifier for the event.</param>
    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(RenderEventDelegate))]
    private static void RunOnRenderThread(int eventID)
    {
        switch (eventID)
        {
            case GL_INIT_EVENT:
                glInit(par1, par2, par3);  // C function with 3 parameters 
                break;
            case GL_DRAW_EVENT:
                glStep();
                GL.InvalidateState();
                break;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("hello-jni")]
    private static extern void glInit(int par1, int par2, int par3);

    [DllImport("hello-jni")]
    private static extern void glStep();
```